# How can I calculate how much cellular or wifi data my react native app has used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I am kinda new to React Native programming and don't know how to calculate how much my application has used internet data or wifi data!

It will be grateful if someone provide any library or reference.

I have used `NetInfo` but I don't guess it provides the statistics, it just provides the connection related details.

Comment: Please, provide information about what you already tried to do in order to calculate cellular / wifi data.

Comment: Hi @Brhaka , I have done just simple demo code where I want to implement like if I click on button then data calculation should start and as I stop it should show result like this much data has been used.

Comment: So basically I have just created UI. and not much other code.

Comment: It would be great if someone just provide the idea or something, I don't want whole code for this @Brhaka